How to hide all content of a type enviroment?
I'm making an book for my students, but i only want to show the proofs for myseft. I decided to make 2 version, have proofs for me and not have for my students.
I defined the proof is between \begin{cm} and \end{cm}.
Is anyway to hidden all of the proof at the same time?

See her: https://www.ctan.org/topic/cond-comp . If I recall correctly, multiaudience seems to be useful for you.

Here is a simple example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/714544/245790
